# How to concatenate spark dataframe columns using Spark sql in databricks

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have two columns called "FirstName" and "LastName" in my dataframe, how can I concatenate this two columns into one.

```
  |Id  |FirstName|LastName|
  |  1 |    A    |   B    |
  |    |         |        |
  |    |         |        |
```

I want to make it like this

```
|Id |FullName |
| 1 |    AB   |     
|   |         |       
|   |         |
```

my query look like this but it raises an error

```
val kgt=spark.sql("""
Select Id,FirstName+' '+ContactLastName AS FullName from tblAA """)

kgt.createOrReplaceTempView("NameTable")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go with the **Spark SQL** solution:

```
spark.sql("select Id, CONCAT(FirstName,' ',LastName) as FullName from NameTable").show(false)
```

**OR**

```
spark.sql( " select Id, FirstName || ' ' ||LastName as FullName from NameTable ").show(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn('FullName', F.concat(F.col('First_name'), F.col('last_name')))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.